# Can't send data through ESP8266

Tags: arduino, udp, at-command, esp8266

I working on project about seat occupancy in which I have used an Arduino, a piezoelectric sensor and an ESP8266. My problem is that I am not able to send data to my PC where an UDP server is running, written in Python.

My real problem is, that I am able to send data, when I use Arduino IDE's serial monitor. It sends and receives data perfectly, but code is not running and I am not able to point out my mistake.

Arduino code:

```cpp
const int seat_no = 2;
const char *ssid = "";
const char *passwd = "";
const char *ip = "192.168.43.250";
const int port = 55056;
const int threshold = 100;

String op;
int i, a, data_size;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting ESP8266");

  Serial1.write("AT+CWJAP=\"");
  Serial1.write(ssid);
  Serial1.write("\",\"");
  Serial1.write(passwd);
  Serial1.write("\"\r\n");
  Serial1.write("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n");
  Serial1.write("AT+CIPMUX=0\r\n");
  Serial1.write("AT+CIPSTART=\"UDP\",\"");
  Serial1.write(ip);
  Serial1.write("\",");
  Serial1.write(port);
  Serial1.write("\r\n");
}
void loop() {
  op = "{\"seat_status\":[";
  for (i = 0; i < seat_no; i++) {
    a = analogRead(i);
    if (a > threshold) {
      op += "\"0\"";
      Serial.println("0");
    }
    else {
      op += "\"1\"";
      Serial.println("1");
    }
    if (i < seat_no - 1)
      op += ",";
  }
  op += "]}";
  data_size = op.length();
  Serial1.write("AT+CIPSEND=");
  Serial1.write(data_size+2);
  Serial1.write("\r\n");
  delay(1000);

  for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    Serial.write(op[i]);
  Serial.println();

  for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++)
    Serial1.write(op[i]);
  Serial1.write("\r\n");
  delay(5000);
}
```

I think my Python code is correct as I am able to receive data from other sources as well (through Android app UDP sender) so help me to rectify this problem.

Circuit Diagram
[image]

Comment: Try swapping the RX/TX pins, so that ESP's RX goes to Mega's TX and vice versa.

Comment: done that nothing comes to serial monitor. ESP8266's Tx connects with arduino's Tx and same for Rx

Comment: I have done every thing swapping pins, using other serial pins, adding delay to each command and none of them have solved my problem.

Comment: The pins should be RX->TX and TX->RX. Also the maximum current draw on the 3.3V pin is 50 mA and the ESP8266 needs 200 mA.

Comment: Otherwise I am out of ideas. Maybe wrong SSID, pass, IP, port, baud rate?

Comment: How should i increase current supply and if current is the issue then why same circuit works when i send commands through serial monitor

Comment: SSID,password,IP,Port,baud rate i have checked these parameters thousands times i am sure these values are not wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the use of `Serial1.write`. It's a lower level function. All it does is send bytes and doesn't convert numbers to their string representation.

When you are writing your port and length of your data to the serial, the `write` function is just sending a byte with that value and not a string.
If you would replace `Serial1` with `Serial` and send the commands back to PC, you would see the mistake.

To actually solve your problem, you should replace all of your `Serial1.write` with `Serial1.print`.

Comment: Good clarifying. Does it need an EOL char or println ?

Comment: He is already printing his own `"\r\n"`, but he could replace it with `Serial1.println()`.

Comment: @gre_gor changing Serial.write to Serial,print shows no result. My problem persists.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I tested the code on my pro micro with a d1 mini and this fixed the problem. The only other change worth mentioning is, that I read module's response from `Serial1` and printed it to `Serial`.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal which Arduino are you using? And how did you use Arduino IDE's serial monitor? With a USB to UART adapter?

Comment: @gre_gor I am using Arduino Mega 2560 And ESP8266. I am using cable available with arduino to connect to my PC

Comment: @HimanshuBansal `Serial1`'s RX/TX pins are on pins 19/18. Is your ESP8266 connected to those?

Comment: Yes if u like i can also send u the circuit diagram i am using [link](https://github.com/himanshu0137/Minor-Project/blob/master/cd_bb.jpg)